# how to stop ajax requests after mouse didn´t move?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a function which sends every second an ajax request as long as the mouse hovers over the .postimagepic element.

Now the problem: I want the ajax request (so probably setinterval function) to stop sending a request every second if the mouse didn´t move for 30 seconds. All my attempts failed with mousemove. :/ Do you have any other ideas or approaches to solve this problem?

jQuery

```
var myInterval;
    $(".postimagepic").hover(function () {
        var link = $(this).attr("src").split("/").pop().split(".", 1)[0];
        myInterval = setInterval(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'time.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    'user':'somerandomname',
                    'topost':link
                },
                success: function() {

                }
            });
        }, 1000);
    }, function () {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myInterval;
var i = 0;
    $(".postimagepic").hover(function () {
        var link = $(this).attr("src").split("/").pop().split(".", 1)[0];
        i = 0;
        myInterval = setInterval(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'time.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    'user':'somerandomname',
                    'topost':link
                },
                success: function() {

                }
            });
            i++;
            if(i == 30) {
               clearInterval(myInterval);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }, function () {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    });
```

The above code just introduces another variable i which would check if 30 seconds elapsed or not, and then clear the interval for you.

Comment: Works very well!! Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/w5L0tc7j/1/

I used the mousemove and mouseleave events. It might not be the best implementation, you could even use the idea of the other guy to use a counter instead of a second timeout.

```
var myInterval = false;
var idleInterval = false;
var counter = 0;
$(function(){
    $('.hover_over_me').mousemove(function(){
    if(!myInterval) {
        clearHoverEvent();
      myInterval = setInterval(function () {
        $('#console').html(++counter);
      }, 1000);
      idleInterval = setInterval(function () {
        clearHoverEvent();
      }, 30000);
    }
  });

  $('.hover_over_me').mouseleave(function(){
    clearHoverEvent();
  });
});

function clearHoverEvent() {
    if(myInterval) {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    myInterval = false;
  }
  if(idleInterval) {
    clearInterval(idleInterval);
    idleInterval = false;
  }
}
```